# Como corrigir o carregamento de objetos no Angular 7?

Tags: angular

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Voce pode observar que ao clicar no checkBox Débitos a lista carrega somente todos os nomes que tenham a palavra débido ao lado, porém não acontece o mesmo quando é marcado o checkBox Multa, erradamente ele carrega os nomes que tenham a palavra débitos ao lado e também que tinham a palavra multa, o comportamento esperado é que ao marcar o checkBox  multa carregasse somente todos os nomes que tenham a palavra multa. E se agrava mais ainda quando marcamos os dois checkBox ele carrega duas vezes o nome que tinham a palavra débido.

Eu conseguir implementar o método que carregar a lista, mas não ficou perfeito porque eu peguei o código e adaptei para o meu context, eu somente preciso ajustar para quando eu marcar o checkBox multa ele somente carregue os nomes que tinham a palavra multa, e quando eu marcar o checkBox débito ele carregue somente todos os nomes que tinham a palavra débito, e se eu marcar os dois ele traga tudo, tanto multas como débitos sem ter duplicidade, e preciso de ajuda.

Esse são os dois métodos responsável pela implementação;

```
  async selecionaTiposDeliberacao(valor) {
    debugger;
      if (!this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes.includes(valor)) {

        this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes.push(valor);

      } else {
         this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes = this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes.filter(v => v != valor);
      }
    debugger;
      if (this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes.length > 0) {
        this.habilitarListaDevedor = false;
          this.listarParticipantesProcesso();
      } else {
        this.tiposDebito   = [];
        this.participantes = [];
        this.idDevedor = undefined;
        this.habilitarCheckCombo = true;
      }

  }

  protected listarParticipantesProcesso() {

    if (this.habilitarListaDevedor == true){
      this.processo = new Processo();

    }

    this.processoService.listarParticipantesProcesso(this.processo.numero, this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (data && data.dataTransfers) {
          debugger;
          this.participantes = data.dataTransfers;
          this.habilitarCheckCombo = false;
         } else {
           this.participantes = [];
           this.habilitarCheckCombo = true;
         }
      }, (error) => {
        this.abrirModalInfo(error.error.header.mensagem, 'Erro', 'danger');
      });
  }
```

Esse é o componente HTML;

```
<div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="radio">
            <label [class.textCinza]="habilitarCheck">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                [disabled]="habilitarCheck"
                (change)="selecionaTiposDeliberacao($event.target.value)"
                value="0"/> Multas
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

 <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="radio">
                <label [class.textCinza]="habilitarCheck">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    [disabled]="habilitarCheck"
                    (change)="selecionaTiposDeliberacao($event.target.value)"
                    value="1"/> Débitos
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: complicado saber o que as funções fazem dentro, internamente

Comment: Eu vou tentar explicar melhor vou reeditar minha postagem!

Comment: Você esó está usando o ultimo tipo selecionado e não todos os selecionados

Comment: Inves de enviar o event target value vc poderia só chamar a função e ela checa quais campos estão checados

Answer (score 0):

No seu filter você deveria fazer algo parecido com

```js
export class myClass implements OnInit {
tipoMulta:boolean;
tipoDebitos: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  selecionaTiposDeliberacao() {
  if(multas && debitos) {
  this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes = 
  this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes.filter(v => v === tipoMulta || v ===       tipoDebitos);
  } else if(multas) {
    this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes = this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes.filter(v => v === tipoMulta);
  } else if(tipoDebitos) {
    this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes = this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes.filter(v =>  v === tipoDebitos);
  } else {
    this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes = this.arrayTipoDeliberacoes;
  }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="radio">
            <label [class.textCinza]="habilitarCheck">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                [disabled]="habilitarCheck"
                 [(ngModel)]="tipoMulta"
                (change)="selecionaTiposDeliberacao()"
                value="0"/> Multas
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

 <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="radio">
              <label [class.textCinza]="habilitarCheck">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  [disabled]="habilitarCheck"
                  [(ngModel)]="tipoDebitos"
                  (change)="selecionaTiposDeliberacao()"
                  value="1"/> Débitos
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

para pegar as váriaveis vc pode usar two way data binding, dessa forma não havendo necessidade de parametro no ação change.
Exemplo

Comment: não ajudou muito porque o método recebe somente um parâmetro na assinatura, e pela sua sugestão é como se o método da assinatura tivesse dois parâmetro, eu iria solicitar que pudesse colocar uma resposta mais completa, por favor.

Comment: Da uma olhada agora.

Comment: Tranquilo, mas uma dúvida, por favor, como as variáveis como "multas", "debitos", "tipoMulta", "tipoDebitos", como elas serial declaradas na classe de componentes do angular?